# MySQL CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY syntax

Tags: mysql, key, constraints

I am new to MySQL and am messing with a database I created just to learn.

I created my first table and it worked OK:

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE Pizzas(ItemID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Size INTEGER, Price DECIMAL);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.90 sec)
```

then I tried to create another table using CONSTRAINT (I was simply copying the way foreign keys were created in a class I am taking) and I got an error:

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE Customers(CustomerID PRIMARY KEY, Name CHAR(20), ItemID INTEGER, CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (ItemID) REFERENCES Pizzas (ItemID));

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'PRIMARY KEY, Name CHAR(20), ItemID INTEGER, CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (ItemID) REFE' at line 1
```

I'm using a linux computer and my MySQL version is 5.5. Why am I getting this problem?

Comment: You don't have a data type (for example `INTEGER`) for `CustomerID`. Also, some advice: use `VARCHAR(20)` instead of `CHAR(20)` for the `Name` column, as `CHAR(20)` will be padded with spaces at the end. You won't see them, but they'll be there and they'll mess you up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your table definition is not correct. you are missing the `datatype` in `CustomerID PRIMARY KEY`. It should be

```
CREATE TABLE Customers(CustomerID int not null PRIMARY KEY,
                                  <-- Here 
Name CHAR(20), ItemID INTEGER, 
CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (ItemID) REFERENCES Pizzas (ItemID));
```